# mysql - join one table with two other tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

```
Products
[id, name]

Purchases
[id, product_id, quantity, date]

Sales
[id, product_id, quantity, date]
```

I want to list all the product with remaining quantity for each product.

I have tried with the following query, but it is not working.

```
SELECT pr.id, pr.name, (sum(pu.quantity))-sum(s.quantity) as quantity 
FROM `products` pr 
join purchase pu ON pu.product_id = pr.id
left join sales s ON s.product_id = pr.id
GROUP BY pr.id
```

I know that the above query creates duplicate rows for `purchase` and `sales` since we are joining both the table with products.

Please help me to write the correct query to find the remaining product quantity

Comment: Could you explain the data in Purchases and Sales - they have a identical fields which seems odd - and the realtionship between the tables?

Comment: @foxbeefly: When we add a product to stock, the `purchases` table will get populates. If we sell a product, it will go the `sales` table. Thats what I think. Do you think, I should combine these two table to a single table, say `product_transactions` ?

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag, because it it does not recognize backticks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to aggregate before the `join`.  One method is explicitly in the `from` clause:

```
SELECT pr.id, pr.name,
       (coalesce(pu.sumq, 0) - coalesce(s.sumq, 0)) as quantity 
FROM `products` pr left join
     (SELECT pu.product_id, SUM(pu.quantity) as sumq
      FROM purchase pu
      GROUP BY pu.product_id
     ) pu
     ON pu.product_id = pr.id left join
     (SELECT s.product_id, SUM(s.quantity) as sumq
      FROM sales s 
      GROUP BY s.product_id
     ) s
     ON s.product_id = pr.id
GROUP BY pr.id, pr.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `IFNULL` instead. Because *12 + null = null*

```
SELECT pr.id, pr.name, 
sum(ifnull(pu.quantity,0))-sum(ifnull(s.quantity,0)) as quantity 
FROM `products` pr 
left join purchase pu ON pu.product_id = pr.id
left join sales s ON s.product_id = pr.id
GROUP BY pr.id,pr.name
```

And since you add `pr.name` in resultset, you also need to put it in `GROUP BY` clause.